My 'animate.css' file is not being recognized on github pages
I recently tried to deploy one of my portfolio projects, the problem is that the animations that I installed using npm from animate.css are not working on the deployed site, but on my local machine are working fine. The configuration I'm using on gh pages is master branch and /root. I find it kinda weird since the style.css file is working good and it is not in the same folder as the index.html file. You can take a look to the directory structure on the linked github repo and this is the website
I tried to run the command npm install gh-pages --save-dev but still not modified any json file.

I would start by following the installation guide on the animate website. Importing the animate.css in your style.css from node_modules might not include them in the GitHub Pages deployment

@JohannesKantz Yeah you were right, I checked the console and it's saying that the animate.css file could not be found. I ended up copy pasting all the animations in use from the animate.css file to the style.css. Thank you!


<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/animate.css/animate.css" />


The file you are trying to include is in /node_modules.
Per documentation (https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/about-github-pages-and-jekyll) this file will not be present.

By default, Jekyll doesn't build files or folders that:

Are located in a folder called /node_modules


Therefore you will need to manually include this resource.

If you want Jekyll to process any of these files, you can use the include setting in your configuration file.

